# lshw command gives no output

Tags: networking

My NIC is operating just fine. I am connected via ethernet right now to a switch on my router and using the internet. However, I came across this online documentation

https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/network-configuration.html

It states:

> Another application that can help identify all network interfaces
>   available to your system is the lshw command. In the example below,
>   lshw shows a single Ethernet interface with the logical name of eth0
>   along with bus information, driver details and all supported
>   capabilities.

However, when I try to emulate the behavior on my machine, I get a blinking cursor followed by a string 'PCI (sysfs)'.  And then that's it. It returns control to terminal. Nothing happens. No information is given as described in documentation. What may I be doing wrong?

Comment: Which command did you type exactly ? Are you running on physical server or a virtual one ? Please specify.

Comment: I ran "sudo lshw -c network" and I am using Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `sudo` like this:

```
sudo lshw -c network
```

It will output only information related to your network devices (eth+wlan)